# How to update the updated_at column when the user logs in?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update the `updated_at` column to the current time, each time a user logs in.

But I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException A four digit year could not be found Data missing

**PHP**

```
$input = Input::all();
$remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

$auth = Auth::attempt([
    'username' => $input['username'],
    'password' => $input['password'],
    'active' => 1
    ],$remember
);

if ($auth) 
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->updated_at = DB::raw('NOW()');
    $user->save();

    if ($user->userType==1) 
    {
        return Redirect::intended('admin');
    }
    elseif ($user->userType==2)
    {
        return Redirect::intended('corporate');
    }
    elseif ($user->userType==3) 
    {
        return Redirect::intended('trainer');
    }
    elseif ($user->userType==4) 
    {
        return Redirect::intended('user');
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you dump `$user->updated_at`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use the Eloquent method `touch()` for this:

```
//instead of
$user->updated_at = DB::raw('NOW()');
$user->save();

// simply this:
$user->touch();
```

Answer (score 10):

For one I would not use the updated_at column as that's the default timestamps name.

You would be better of with last_login

And just use the PHP date method.

```
$user->updated_at = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Depending on your app, I don't see why using updated_at is off limits. Isn't that what updated_at is used for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're accidentally assigning a value instead of using array syntax. eg:

```
Model::create([
    'key'='val'
]);
```

instead of:

```
Model::create([
    'key'=>'val'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In reply to @Kirk Beard $user->touch(); works great for this instance!

Please be aware that if you want to update a model its needs to be dirty. Which means that at least one model attribute must be changed. If you set a model attribute value and its stays the same. The model is NOT dirty. Forcing a new updated_at date like @Lee works create for this. (one small change)

```
$user->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user->save();
```

Please be aware that the `G` returns a non-leading 0 value.

In example: `2024-02-05 1:24:20`

Which might result in an incorrect mysql datetime string. Use `H` instead.

Which results in: `2024-02-05 01:24:20`