# Carbon::now() wrong date and time

Tags: laravel, datetime, timestamp, migration, php-carbon

Current UTC time is: 2022-08-19 00:50

When I create a new record in my database I set `created_at` like:

```
'created_at' => Carbon::now()
```

But it stores Datetime like this -> `2022-08-18 20:50`

Anyways, after couple of minutes I update this record and set `updated_at` like:

```
'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
```

And it stores it like this -> `2022-08-19 00:50` which is correct but not completely, because couple of minutes passed and it should be like `2022-08-19 00:53`

Here is my migration file:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamp('created_at');
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

/config/app.php:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

My Item Model:

```
class Item extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Seriously, whats wrong with this datetime thing in laravel? Why it doesn't work like every other frameworks?

**Note:** I'm sick of laravels default `$table->timestamps()` it works even worse.

Comment: can you print `Carbon::now()->timezoneName;`

Comment: Also print Carbon::now(); should be useful

Comment: It returns ```UTC``` @parth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a problem related to database.

When you create a column this way `$table->timestamp('created_at')`, it creates a column in database with this structure:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Name            Type        ...        Null        Default              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    created_at      timestamp               No         current_timestamp()  |
|                                                                            |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

If you pay attention to the `Default` column, you find out that this function uses the mysql server timestamp to set value for the `created_at` column and ignores your entry in laravel `create()` method.

To fix this problem you only have to set `created_at` to a `nullable` column like so:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer listed here might be useful: [How to update the updated_at column when the user logs in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132758/how-to-update-the-updated-at-column-when-the-user-logs-in)

```
//instead of
'created_at' => Carbon::now()

// simply this:
$user->touch();
```

Comment: I don't use laravel default timestamps ```$table->timestamps()``` so touching a user won't do anything.